# What's this tiny airplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I found this very small airplane in the desert on Google Maps. It appears to have about 
a 10 foot wingspan, and is about the size of an SUV (compare to cars nearby).

[image: airplane]

Location in Google Maps: [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/35%C2%B054'10.9%22N+117%C2%B043'51.6%22W/@35.6717802,-117.7438959,150m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d35.9030167!4d-117.7309917)

Comment: Since its near the Naval Air Weapons facility in China Lake, I'd guess that it is a target drone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would make this a comment since I can't be certain, but I wanted to put some photos in. I concur with Ron that it's a target drone. But *what* target drone?

The one next to it appears to be a [Ryan BQM-34 Firebee](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/BQM34Firebee/Pages/default.aspx).

The most likely possibility is the [Beachcraft MQM-107 Streaker](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_MQM-107_Streaker).

Here is a chart of US target drones.

[image]
[source](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.dtic.mil/ndia/2011targets/WednesdayTorgerson.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjOleKctt7PAhVJeSYKHZKzCfUQFggTMAM&sig2=FvsnnBUHPMKv3BqgWbnNxA&usg=AFQjCNETVGQLFPAiIbSIk-IF0ob1d0tEkw)

Comment: The Lahshya doesn't look right. Maybe a MQM-107B Streaker or similar variant? Doesn't seem exactly right, but seems close.

Comment: I'd expect to see at least a hint of a shadow on the inboard section of the right wing if it was a low wing.  Also, the horizintal seem wider than on the orange drone. Maybe just me, but the nose looks to have a "spike" on the nose (similar to a MiG21). My knee jerk reaction is some kind of old cruise missile that was never test fired. Not sure that makes much sense though. Why leave it out in the open...unless to be photographed by the soviets.

Comment: Now I am thinking it looks like a variant of a BQM-74. Length is in the right range, at 15 ft, high wing. Wing shape doesn't match any -74 variants I can find, though.

Comment: It looks like a display of different drone aircraft. The BQM-34, the A6's to the left, Not sure if that's a P-51, but I think they made target drones out of them too.

Comment: @ymb1 I've convinced myself it has to be one of the MQM-107 variants. Not sure which one, but the A variant is likely. I think that larger aircraft there is an F-8 which were also made into target drones